# Writting efficient trigger way

Tags: apex, trigger, bestpractice

I have the below piece of code:

```
 List<Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c> jobopening= [ Select id,Job_Opening__c from Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c WHERE ID IN:trigger.newMap.keyset()];

    Map<Id, Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c> JobopeningMap = new  Map<Id, Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c>();

    for(Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c Joskillset: jobopening){

        JobopeningMap.put(Joskillset.Job_Opening__c, Joskillset);
    }
```

I would like to write it as below, but it throws an error saying - first object should be concreate Sobject.

```
 Map<Id, Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c> JobopeningMap = new  Map<Id, Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c>();
for(List<Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c> jobopening : [ Select id,Job_Opening__c from Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c WHERE ID IN:trigger.newMap.keyset()]){

JobopeningMap.put(jobopening .Job_Opening__c, jobopening );
}
```

But this piece of code throws an error , how can resolve this error.

Comment: What line is the error in?

Comment: Initial term of the field expression must be a concrete Sobject

Comment: The line, please, not the message....

Comment: The line where I use put for the map , inside the for loop

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code, except the space between `jobopening` and `. Job_Opening__c`

Comment: Not sure why I get an error. I get an error at - JobopeningMap.put(jobopening .Job_Opening__c, jobopening ); Where it says - Initial term of field expression must be a concrete Sobject:List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem (with a little help from an unnamed resource).

Rewrite this line

```
for(List<Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c> jobopening : [ Select id,Job_Opening__c from Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c WHERE ID IN:trigger.newMap.keyset()]){
```

like this

```
for(Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c jobopening : [ Select id,Job_Opening__c from Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c WHERE ID IN:trigger.newMap.keyset()]){
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
for(List<Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c> jobopening : [ Select id,Job_Opening__c
      from Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c WHERE ID IN:trigger.newMap.keyset()]){}
```

this return records in a list with 200 size which can be processed later but as you are inside trigger your code itself running in 200 chunk so as far as i know above code will not make any difference but if you still want to write you can use following code

```
Map<Id, Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c> JobopeningMap = new  Map<Id, Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c>();
for(List<Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c> jobopening : [ Select id,Job_Opening__c from Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c WHERE ID IN:trigger.newMap.keyset()]){

        //loop over above list of records.
        for(Job_Opening_Skill_Set__c singleJobopening : jobopening){
           JobopeningMap.put(jobopening .Job_Opening__c, singleJobopening);
        }
}
```

Comment: I read that if I use the way I used before , the heap size might exceed 6MB if it returns lot of records in the list

Comment: as I said earlier because you are running this code in trigger, size is limited to 200 records only so you are good to go with this solution. querying data in list inside for loop is required if you are running code in a apex class :)